# How to use a list of fractions with foreach?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath, tikz-node

I want to use the list of fractions `flist` to label some angles. They will be in the place of the "A".

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\edef\r{1}
    \edef\anglist{{30,45,60,120,135,150,210,225,240,300,315,330}}
    %\edef\flist{{\frac{\pi}{6}, \frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{\pi}{3}, \frac{2\pi}{3}, \frac{3\pi}{4}, \frac{5\pi}{6}, \frac{7\pi}{6}, \frac{5\pi}{4}, \frac{4\pi}{3}, \frac{5\pi}{3}, \frac{7\pi}{4}, \frac{11\pi}{6}}}
    \foreach \a in{0,...,11}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmp}{\flist[\ang]};
        \draw[cycle1] (0,0)--({\r*cos(\anglist[\a])},{\r*sin(\anglist[\a])})node[pos=1.3]{$A$};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I don't know where is the mistake, but the code above doesn't works.

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: `\frac{a}{b}` is intended for typesetting a fraction, you seem to want to calculate `a/b`. `pgfmath` doesn't understand `\frac`, but it does understand `/`, so just use that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tikz `\foreach` construct supports looping on pairs, precisely to allow what you wish to do.

### The output

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  % join this
  %30 /\frac{\pi}{6},
  %45 /\frac{\pi}{4},
  %60 /\frac{\pi}{3},
  %120/\frac{2\pi}{3},
  %135/\frac{3\pi}{4},
  %150/\frac{5\pi}{6},
  %210/\frac{7\pi}{6},
  %225/\frac{5\pi}{4},
  %240/\frac{4\pi}{3},
  %300/\frac{5\pi}{3},
  %315/\frac{7\pi}{4},
  %330/\frac{11\pi}{6},
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \def\r{1}
    \foreach \cAngle/\dAngle in {30/\frac{\pi}{6},45/\frac{\pi}{4},60/\frac{\pi}{3},120/\frac{2\pi}{3},135/\frac{3\pi}{4},150/\frac{5\pi}{6},210/\frac{7\pi}{6},225/\frac{5\pi}{4},240/\frac{4\pi}{3},300/\frac{5\pi}{3},315/\frac{7\pi}{4},330/\frac{11\pi}{6}}
    {
        \draw (0,0)--({\r*cos(\cAngle)},{\r*sin(\cAngle)}) node[pos=1.3]{$\dAngle$};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```